# multiple different SQL update commands in C# codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-update, code-behind

Very new to ASP.net here, so please keep responses simple.

I am trying to have one button run many different update commands on different tables to update the same info. I've found many sites talking about how to do similar things, but nothing close enough that I could get it working for my purposes. Right now I have

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

protected void cancel_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("biosupdate.aspx");
}

protected void update_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AccessDataSource1.UpdateCommand = "UPDATE [1U] SET [bios] = ? WHERE [mobogroup] = ?";
    AccessDataSource1.Update();

    AccessDataSource1.UpdateCommand = "UPDATE [EB] SET [bios] = ? WHERE [mobogroup] = ?";
    AccessDataSource1.Update();

    AccessDataSource1.UpdateCommand = "UPDATE [PPC] SET [bios] = ? WHERE [mobogroup] = ?";
    AccessDataSource1.Update();
}
```

but this will ignore the first two sets and just update [PPC] or whatever the last set in the group is. I've tried putting `Thread.Sleep(1000);` in between the sets in case each operation just needed more time to finish or something, but as I had assumed it did nothing. I have also tried using UNION or ; to string multiple commands together, but still got nowhere.

Any suggestions on how to get this to work? or possibly even on a better way to achieve this same result?

Comment: What does the ASP.Net markup look like for the control that is firing off the `update_click` event?  Is the last `UPDATE` statement the one that is hard-coded into the `AccessDataSource1.UpdateCommand` by default in the markup page source?  It's possible your `update_click` method is not actually ever running, as the code looks fine as far as I can tell.

Comment: The button itself is just
   <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" OnClick="update_click" Text="Confirm Update" CommandName="Update" />
and there is no hard coded update command right now. I was afraid that might mess with the updates from the code behind.

Comment: Well since you said `CommandName="Update"`, your button is functioning as firing update command, if it is embedded inside of the data control (i.e., `GridView` or `DetailsView`).  But I thought `.Update()` would override the behavior.  Checking the docs...

Comment: yeah, I think you're right that the button is the update command. I just tried removing it from the button and now nothing updates, so the codebehind AccessDataSource.Update() lines are not doing anything.
and its actually a formview (I assume that doesn't matter, but just in case...)

Comment: Hmm, that is very strange.  Can you try debugging and stepping through the code, and see if the lines of code in `update_click` even fire at all?  Or for instance, drop a `Response.Write("HERE");` to see if it is hit.  Meanwhile I'll try a test here... **Edit**: I just tried a test where I used `MyDataSource.Update` and it worked just fine.  Can you provide more code related to the update from the beginning of the `Page_Load`, in case something else is stopping that event from properly running?

Comment: OK, updated the original post. There's really not much on this page so I doubt its anything else blocking it. In your test did you're button have commandname="update"?

Comment: Are you sure your UPDATEs are correct? Maybe they just run without any effect. You might use SQL Server Profiler to see what actual queries are sent to SQL server.

Comment: The UPDATEs all work individually, or if they are the last one in the group, its only when they are anything but last that they get skipped over.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your AccessDataSource1, you are replacing the *UpdateCommand* 2 times.
What you can do ?
1 - Execute your SQL after each.
2 - Creater *AccessDataSource2* and *AccessDataSource3*

Comment: What's wrong with setting the `UpdateCommand`?  Shouldn't that work just as well?

Comment: hmm, I thought the AccessDataSource1.Update(); line was executing the SQL, that would explain its behavior. What is the actual command to execute this between each update?